# Trying to get if statement to determine 'context' of addon app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm working this Google Workspace Add-on app, I'm trying to get a function that sets the appropriate function for calling the document id depending on if it's called in the context of drive, docs, sheets, etc.

```js
function checkContext(event){
  var itemId;
  Logger.log(event)
   if (DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId() != null && DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId() != undefined)
   {
      itemId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
      Logger.log(itemId);
      }
  else if (e.drive.selectedItems[0].id != null && e.drive.selectedItems[0].id != undefined){  
    var itemId = e.drive.selectedItems[0].id;
          Logger.log(itemId);

}
  else if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId() != null && SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId() != undefined){  
    var itemId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
          Logger.log(itemId);

}
  else {  
    var itemId = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId();
          Logger.log(itemId);

}
```

As you can see, I've attempted to achieve this with a nested if statement, where the `itemId` variable is set to the appropriate context depending on which getId() does NOT fail. Despite my best efforts, I always get the

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of null

error every time the my function is triggered.

Comment: What's the event?

Comment: an onHomePage trigger? Not sure what this means to be honest. I would post the logged contents of the event but it's too long.

Comment: [addon event objects](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/event-objects?hl=en)

Comment: It looks like the [commonEventObject.hostApp](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/event-objects?hl=en#common_event_object) is what you're looking for.  Yes/No?

Comment: omg. I think that's it. Let me see if I can get that to work!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up with, using Cooper's insight about `commonEventObjects`. This function returns the a string for getting a document ID in the appropriate context. The returned string can then be run with `eval()`to return a doc id in function with the same `event`.

```js
function serveDocCall(event){
  var context = event.commonEventObject.hostApp
  var docCall; 
  if (context == "DOCS")
   {docCall = 'DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()';
      Logger.log(docCall);}
  else if (context == "DRIVE"){  
    var docCall = 'event.drive.selectedItems[0].id';
          Logger.log(docCall);}
  else if (context == "SHEETS"){  
    var docCall = 'SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()';
          Logger.log(docCall);}
  else {  
    var docCall = 'SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId()';
          Logger.log(docCall);}
  return docCall;
}
```